# Remove lines that contain non-english (Ascii) characters from a file

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, grep

I have a text file with characters from different languages like (chinese, latin etc)

I want to remove all lines that contain these non-English characters. I want to include all English characters (a-b), numbers (0-9) and all punctuations.

How can I do it using unix tools like awk or sed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Perl supports an `[:ascii:]` character class.

```
perl -nle 'print if m{^[[:ascii:]]+$}' inputfile
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Awk, provided you force the use of the C locale:

```
LC_CTYPE=C awk '! /[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]/' my_file
```

The environment variable `LC_TYPE=C` (or `LC_ALL=C`) force the use of the C locale for character classification. It changes the meaning of the character classes (`[:alnum:]`, `[:space:]`, etc.) to match only ASCII characters.

The `/[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]/` regex match lines with any non ASCII character. The `!` before the regex invert the condition. So only lines without any non ASCII characters will match. Then as no action is given, the default action is used for matching lines (`print`).

EDIT: This can also be done with grep:

```
LC_CTYPE=C grep -v '[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]' my_file
```

Answer (score 4):

With GNU grep, which supports perl compatible regular expressions, you can use:

```
grep -P '^[[:ascii:]]+$' file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `egrep -v` to return only lines *not* matching the pattern and use something like `[^ a-zA-Z0-9.,;:-'"?!]` as pattern (include more punctuation as needed).

Hm, thinking about it, a double negation (`-v` and the inverted character class) is probably not that good. Another way might be `^[ a-zA-Z0-9.,;:-'"?!]*$`.

You can also just filter for ASCII:

```
egrep -v "[^ -~]" foo.txt
```

Comment: I need all the punctuation. So is it possible to just filter out all non-ascii characters, instead of specifying the list of allowed characters?

Comment: It's perhaps tangential to your main point, but the range [a-z] includes non-ascii characters in some locales.  For example, on my system, `echo é | grep [a-z]` does find the é.